# Remove zombie buffers from recentf

Tags: buffers, recentf

I want to get rid of invalid recentf entries, that is buffers that no longer exist on disk, because I renamed or just plain deleted them ; I just did a `M-x recentf-cleanup` and apparently lost all my history :/ what would be a sure and safe way to clean this list up?

Comment: What's the value of the variable `recentf-exclude` and the value of `recentf-keep`?

Answer (score 2):

`recentf-cleanup` shouldn't remove all your history. According to the documentation (`C-h f recentf-cleanup RET`):

> recentf-cleanup is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> ‘recentf.el’.
>
> (recentf-cleanup)
>
> Cleanup the recent list.
> That is, remove **duplicates**, **non-kept**, and **excluded files**.

One can also edit recentf list manually with the following bit of elisp :

```lisp
(delete "/the/file/you/want/to/remove.example" recentf-list)
```

(I'm not an expert, it may introduce bugs or there's probably a cleaner/more appropriate way to do it, I don't know. But it appears to work on my emacs.)

Edit : There's also :

`M-x recentf-edit-list RET`

> recentf-edit-list is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
> ` recentf.el'.
>
> (recentf-edit-list)
>
> Show a dialog to delete selected files from the recent list.